# Does Holly Short get to say goodbye to her mom?

Tags: artemis-fowl, eoin-colfer

I just finished re-reading the *Artemis Fowl* series, books 1-8. There were a couple of things that I seem to remember happening from the first time I read the series, a while ago, but that I didn't read this time through.

I'm trying to figure out if I am remembering wrong or if there was an extra section that I missed. I know there is [extra content](https://artemisfowl.fangathering.com/books/codes/) for the codes printed on the bottom of every page of the books, but I didn't find it there either.

What I seem to remember is that Artemis provides Holly with an opportunity to have a hologram-call back in time to speak to her mother, Coral Short, just before she dies in the submarine. They had done it that way so that time as they know it would not change, since her mother would not be able to prevent her death. I know she got to say goodbye to Commander Root, but I seem to remember this, too.

I also remember Artemis coming back from some time changes, seeing his parents, and finding that his brothers no longer exist.

Do either of these happen in any of the books or somewhere else? Or am I remembering incorrectly?